# Is it possible to return the event function in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, events, function, return

Does anyone know if you can return a function for an event in jQuery? For example:

```
$(e).bind('ev', function(){
 alert('Hello world!');
});

$(e).getEvent('ev'); // returns function(){alert('Hello world!');};
```

I don't even know if returning a function is possible in JavaScript at all. Just curious.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)...

```
$(e).data('events');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/qPFMK/).

Or more specifically, in your case...

```
$(e).data('events').click[0].handler.toString();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/gwFjw/).